# OOP CMS object design for accessing the database

Tags: php, oop, content-management-system

I'm trying to make a small cms in php and mysql, and want it to be object-oriented

I have a class DbConnector that handles all sql queries. Then I have some other classes that needs to alter the database through the DbConnector.

As I see i I have to either send the DbConnector instance as a parameter in every class initialization, or I can make a new DbConnector instance for each class, which to me seems pretty unnecessary.

What is the preferred way to do this or is it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of doing this would be [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), the lazy / easy / OK for small scale way could be a [Singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton) database object.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should give you +1 for Dependency Injection or -1 for Singleton... ;)

Comment: Well, I tried to word it somewhat negatively with *lazy*, but had to mention it as Singletons are bound to creep up in other answers. But rest assured, I'm happy with the 0-average :)